# how to capture JS errors using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code:

## to find javascript errors on entire website

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

import net.jsourcerer.webdriver.jserrorcollector.JavaScriptError;  //jar file used

public class js
{

private static WebDriver driver; 
@BeforeClass public static void setUp() throws IOException
{
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    JavaScriptError.addExtension(ffProfile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile); 
    driver.get("WEBSITE NAME"); /*have to check all pages of a website*/
    
    } 

@AfterClass public static void tearDown() 
{ 
    List<JavaScriptError> jsErrors = JavaScriptError.readErrors(driver);
    System.out.println("###start displaying errors");
    for(int i = 0; i < jsErrors.size(); i++) 
    { 
    System.out.println(jsErrors.get(i).getErrorMessage()); 
    System.out.println(jsErrors.get(i).getLineNumber()); 
    System.out.println(jsErrors.get(i).getSourceName());
    }
    System.out.println("###start displaying errors"); 
    driver.close(); driver.quit();
  }
@Test 
public void returnJavascriptErrors() throws InterruptedException { 
    Thread.sleep(5000); 
}
}
```

It is working but how do I get all the pages checked on the website. it shows 0 errors, I am wondering if it it checking only home page

Comment: What do you mean by "all the pages checked on the website"?

Comment: I mean look for js errors on my website